# Archimedean Property Proof from Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have a small question about how to interpret the proof from Rudin's text. Is it correct to say that "for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, there is another real number $nx$ that is larger?"

I thought that the archimedean property was supposed to show that every $y \in \mathbb{R}$ was bounded above by an integer (or is it supposed to be an integer multiple of a real number)?

I am just a bit confused about the wording of Rudin's theorem and the theorem from this thread (not sure which text the theorem comes from)

[This Proof of Archimedean Property seems wrong.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507834/this-proof-of-archimedean-property-seems-wrong)

Thanks in advance for the clarification

Comment: There are many equivalent ways to phrase the Archimedean property. One is the one given in Rudin: given any two positive real numbers, if you “add” the first one to itself enough times, it will eventually surpass the second. Another is the one you mention: every positive real number is bounded above by an integer/natural number (to see the one in Rudin implies this, just pick $x=1$). Yet another is that for every positive real number $y$ there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\lt y$. It will be a nice exercise to verify that they all imply one another.

Comment: No, your rephrasing is not quite right. The better phrasing is: for any *two* real numbers, $y$ and $x\gt 0$, if you add $x$ to itself enough times, you will eventually surpass $y$.” What you wrote is confusing because you never say what $nx$ means or represents, just that $y$ is arbitrary.

Comment: A corollary of 1.20, (a) is (by letting $x=1$) that for any $y\in \Bbb R$ there exists $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $n>y.$  An ever-useful result of this is that  if $x\in \Bbb R$ and $0\le x\le 1/n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ then $x=0$..... We can extend $\Bbb R$ to  a larger ordered field  $R^*$ that has "numbers" that are $>0$ but less than any positive member of $\Bbb R.$ But we lose something: In $R^*$ there will be some non-empty subsets with lower bounds but no glbs.